# Do points roll over if I don't spend them all during level up?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

When I level up, I get points to put into Mechanics, Stealth etc. If I don't use them all, will the excess points be added to my total the next time I level up?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You do not lose unused points. In fact, at about level 7 (+/-) for any particular skill, you will need more than the 6 points to increase it, which can only be achieved by deferring the purchase until the next level.

(I think that the formula it is 1+{current skill level} to advance, but no official source for that)

Comment: I have at one point observed, that the game likes the skills being equal - that is increasing one left-behind skill decreased the cost of of another skills next level. I don't have raw data of that at the moment though, so I might have misremembered.